# Idiomatic way to write math expression in Haskell

Tags: haskell, operators, symbolic-math

I want to write down math expressions using Haskell.
For example:

```
foo = (3 * 'x' + 2 * 'y' -- => 3x+2y
```

Is there a way to rewrite the implementation from below in such way that `Add` and `Mul` could be replaced by operators `+` and `*` respectively?

```
data Expr = Const Integer
          | Var Char
          | Add Expr Expr
          | Mul Expr Expr
          deriving (Show)
 ...
 foo =  Add (Mul (Const 3)  (Var 'x')) (Mul (Const 3) (Var 'y'))
```

Ugly as hell. 
Using TypeOperators won't work too, it requires operators to be preceded by `:`.

```
infixl 4 :+:
infixl 5 :*:, :/:
infixr 6 :^:

data Expr = Const Integer
          | Var Char
          | Expr :+: Expr
          | Expr :*: Expr
          | Expr :^: Expr
          | Expr :/: Expr
          deriving (Eq, Show)
```

The declaration of expression would become:

```
foo = (Const 3 :*: Var 'x') :+: (Const 2 :*: Var 'y')
```

Less ugly, but still bad. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.String

data Expr = Const Integer
          | Var Char
          | Add Expr Expr
          | Mul Expr Expr
          deriving (Show)

instance Num Expr where
  (+) = Add
  (*) = Mul
  fromInteger = Const
  abs = undefined
  signum = undefined
  negate = undefined

instance IsString Expr where
  fromString s = Var (head s)

main = do
  let expr = 3 * "x" + 2 * "y" :: Expr
  print expr
```

Comment: I just realized you could supply a definition for `negate` -- `negate x = (-1) * x`. Unfortunately the default definition (`0-x`) doesn't work because we don't have subtraction. Alternatively we could define `a - b = a + (-1) * b` and get `negate` for free.

Comment: Sounds neat. But what if I add `Negate` type constructor into `Expr`? What are the advantages/disadvantages of having `Negate("x")` instead of `Mul (-1) ("x")` ? I saw some people doing it, but I don't understand the reasons behind it. I can only guess that is to facilitate implementing of functions that deal with `Expr`. `simplify` for instance.

Answer (score 4):

You can create an instance of Num/Real for your expression data type.

```
instance Num Expr where
    a + b = Add a b
    a * b = Mul a b
    fromIntegral a = Const a

x = Var 'x'
y = Var 'y'

result = 2 * x + 3 * y
```